# Appropriate Color expression to use in situation

Tags: reporting-services, expression

Hi there i currently have a text like the following being put out on a Report Table:

```
Done:16 of 16 Processed; 7 Errors.
```

Now i want every row that has anynumber of Errors higher than 0 to be Red (Coral)
the simple idea would be something in the lines of:

```
=iif(Fields!LastStatus.Value like "*1 Errors*","Coral","White")
```

but as you can see, i would have to guess the amount which is to be displayed before the Word Errors.
Is there a way for me to take the amount which Comes in before the word "Errors" turn that into a int ( CInt()) and then compare it: Number > 0, Coral, White.
Is this possible, and if so how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're only checking for zero or non-zero, assuming your column has a well known output, you should be able to do this with a slightly modified expression:

```
=iif(not Fields!LastStatus.Value like "* 0 Error*","Coral","White")
```

The key here is that I'm including the leading space in the comparision string, thus avoiding false positives on *10*, *130*, etc, and but only checking up to `Error` we avoid any issues with pluralisation.

This catches zero error rows as required while working for other values as expected:

[image]

You could certainly do this but extracting the numeric portion, converting it to `int`, etc, but this seems like it will work and is written in what is to me a much more intuitive and readable way.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your great Answer, sadly i am trying to get everything that has an Error, so 1 Errors or more, to be red.
i tried using what you gave me by switching the Colors, but i wasn't very succesfull, hence using it with "like"

Comment: Sorry, silly mistake on my part... I've amended the answer slightly to make it fit what you actually want!

Comment: This gets everything other than the 0 values Red,
mind you there are different possibilities for the Values the given
field might have, some might be in the form of "E-Mail sent to @@@" or so.
I'm gonna mark your Response Answer anyways though, if you have a solution for that, feel free to post it
Thank you